# Atomic Codeigniter migrations

Tags: codeigniter, atomic, database-migration

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.3 and have just started to implement migrations as documented [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html). As I'm new to these kind of migrations I tend to make mistakes and when applying the migrations my database is left in an inconsistent state, halfway between the previous migration and the new one.

Is there any easy way to make the migrations atomic? So either they succeed or fail, and there is no in-between state.

Answer (score 0):

As the `CI_Migration` core class is not extendable it seems that the only way to do this (short of replacing the entire class) is to manually use transactions in your migrations:

```
class Migration_Add_parent extends CI_Migration {

    public function up() {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE people ADD COLUMN parent int;');
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE people ADD CONSTRAINT people_parent_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES people (id);');
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }

    public function down() {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE people DROP CONSTRAINT people_parent_fkey;');
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE people DROP COLUMN parent;');
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }
}
```